# Using a common folder in npm project

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, webpack

I have a vue project with multiple clients. The clients all have similar components which I keep in a "common" folder:

```
clients
-- client1
---- ...
-- client2
---- ...
-- client3
---- ...
-- common
---- imports.js
---- ...
```

Right now each project has it's own package.json and node_modules, If I need a common dependency installed I just install it in "common" and import it in "common\imports.js" which is used by my clients.

I also have an alias in webpack `"common": "../common"` to import the common files.

It all works good but the problem is that some packages (like "vue", "vuex") exist in node_modules of "common" and in the clients and it's being loaded twice.

**How can I add the common folder to my clients' node_modules so they won't duplicate versions of the same library?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote how I linked all my clients to my common library in this question:

[Webpack using wrong node_modules folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58475408/webpack-using-wrong-node-modules-folder)

And as for the duplicate library error, I wrote how I overcame it in the answer.